# NUnit Adapter 3.0.10.0: Test execution and Visual Studio Test Execution

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, nunit-console

I am using NUnit Adapter 3.0.10.0  to execute my tests. Before I was implementing N Unit Adapter to convert the tests I was using Visual Studio 2015 to run the tests. When I did this and my test failed I could see the output as to why my test would fail, but now that NUnit is running the test they just hang (In Visual studio when I am clicking the test it just appears like it is still running in Test Explorer but the test is just hanging and keep trying to run with no indication error. How do I use Visual studio to run the tests again?